# Verifying user app license from server side using Google Play Licensing for paid app

Tags: android, server, licensing, google-play, api

In https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/server-side-verification it was said that it is possible to perform license verification check on a server.

[image]

The step for server-side license verification is as follows :

1. Your app makes a request to Google Play, inquiring about whether a particular user has purchased or downloaded a legitimate copy of your app.
2. Google Play responds by sending a response data object, an object of type ResponseData, to your app. This object is a signed piece of information that states whether the user has purchased or downloaded a legitimate copy of your app.
3. Your app makes a request to a private server that you control, verifying the contents of the response data.

However the page didn't specify how to perform license verification on server side. It was said to use License Verification Library (LVL), but if i'm not mistaken, the library is for client side and for android device, not for server.

So my question is, how to perform license verification on my server? I haven't found anywhere how to do it. I need to verify that user that enter my app multiplayer server is legitimate user that have bought the game.